# Creating a class instance using a string

Tags: ios, string, swift, class, instance

I am trying to create an instance of a class using a string, and passing it a value as well. This is the current way I'm doing it:

```
var scene = Level1(size: self.size)
```

I would need to have something like this:

```
var levelId = 1
var scene = imaginaryFunction("Level\(levelId)", self.size)
// scene should be an instance of Level1 class

levelId++
var scene2 = imaginaryFunction("Level\(levelId)", self.size)
// scene2 should be an instance of Level2 class

levelId += 8
var scene3 = imaginaryFunction("Level\(levelId)", self.size)
// scene3 should be an instance of class Level10
```

Comment: Your "LevelPresent1" is a class, not an instance of it. You are unable to "create a new class by using a string" you can create a new instance of your class by using a string if your class has an initializer that accepts an string as the argument.

Comment: No... that's not what I'm trying to do. I want to determine the class to create by using a string. For example, I have classes ``Level1``, ``Level2`` and ``Level3`` and I want to assign an instance of one of those classes to ``var scene``, but I want to determine which of those 3 classes to pick by using a string.

Comment: I'd go for using a Switch statement, switch on the string and return the class

Comment: That's the way Im doing it now (using only an int though) but I was hoping to make this by just calling a string

Comment: The fact that I need to post this 3rd comment determined it is "unclear what you are asking" (and I still do not really have a clue) You might want to edit your question and put info on what you expect. Do you want a function which takes a string as argument and returns a class instance in regards to that string? or what exactly is it that you want??

Comment: I added more examples.

Comment: Let say you can create those levels from strings (check out `NSClassFromString`), what are you gonna do then? How do you know what level is of what type, what methods to call on them and etcetera. In all cases, you will be better with a protocol and a generic.

Comment: @ZoffDino That logic is already built. I set the level Id int before switching to the scene. And I am indeed looking for something like ``NSClassFromString``, is it possible to send it a parameter? Unless there is another way of initiating a ``SKScene`` and sending the view later? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following, but it may not offer any advantage over the Swift's generic and protocols:

```
// This protocol defines the common initializer for all Level classes
protocol MyLevelProtocol {
    init (size : Int)
}

@objc(Level1) // This defines the ObjC name of the class. Needed for NSClassFromString
class Level1 : MyLevelProtocol {
    required init (size : Int) {
        // Do your init
    }
}

@objc(Level2)
class Level2 : MyLevelProtocol {
    required init (size : Int) {
        // Do your init
    }
}

func getLevelFromString(levelName : String, size : Int) -> AnyObject? {
    if let levelClass = NSClassFromString(levelName) as? MyLevelProtocol.Type {
        return levelClass.init(size: size) as? AnyObject
    } else {
        // Level not found
        return nil
    }
}

let scene1 = getLevelFromString("Level1", size: 1)
let scene2 = getLevelFromString("Level2", size: 4)
```

Comment: why return `AnyObject`? you should just leave it as `MyLevelProtocol`